# Loading the old database again and again using titanium

Tags: javascript, mobile, titanium

Hi I have come across a strange problem.I have update the database using sqlite manager in firefox and has replaced the old one and clean my project too but it is loading the old database again again

This is my code:

```
            Ti.Database.install('scimed.sqlite', 'scimed');
            var db = Ti.Database.open('scimed');
```

could anyone tell me what is the problem with this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your old database is loaded in your device / emulator.

When you use `Ti.Database.install('scimed.sqlite', 'scimed');`, according to the [Titanium doc](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Database-method-install), if the .sqlite file is already copied in the database path of the device / emulator, it will only open it.

You have to delete the .sqlite file in your project and replace it with the new database.

Then, clean your project, delete your app in your device / emulator, and re-build it.

Answer (score 1):

You  need to delete the project / app from the simulator or device your testing on. The database is still there and you can't install over it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are installing on the device , manually uninstall the app first , the clean and build the app to install on device.